# Дополнительный IP на debian 9

Tags: ip

Всем привет! Возникла непонятная проблема с добавлением дополнительного IP:

- прописал через /etc/network/interfaces
- прописал в etc/hostname
- прописал в /etc/hosts
- добавил A и MX запись в днс у регистратора
- добавил днс-записи в Весте
- в апаче прописал ServerName д
- добавил виртуальный хост -НО - все письма все равно идут с первого IP.
  В чем тут может быть дело?

перенесено из «ответа»:

Дополнительный IP, который я купил у хостинга, failover IP, если быть точным.
Рассылаю через mailwizz, в настройка прописан хост, к которому привязан дополнительный IP, который прописан в днс.
Почему все эти действия не имеют отношения к исходящему IP? Как тогда его добавляют в систему?

Comment: Какое отношение имеет апач к отправляемой почте ? Вы через что ее отправляете ? Смотрите настройки программы, которая в вашей системе отвечает за отправку почты во вне.

Comment: Да и вообще ни одно из перечисленных действий, кроме первого, не имеет отношения к исходящему ip

Comment: да и что именно ты подразумеваешь под «дополнительным IP»?